# How to seam these holes in my object?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I tried to merge the vertices by distance but it didnt work..
I dont know what do to. Any help?
[image]

[image]

Comment: you probably need to dissolve all the isolated vertices we see along the edges, have you tried?

Comment: no idea how. i am a beginner, im going  to search it up on yt but can you explain if you have time? just in case

Comment: please share your object here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PLxOKxnV
i hope its right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh is a bit messy, you have floating edge along its axis, you can see if you hide some faces:

[image]

What you could do to fix it quickly is enabling the *Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Move the origin very slightly to the right:

[image]

Disable the option, then back in *Edit* mode, select all, go in the *Mesh* menu > *Symmetrize*:

[image]

In the *Operator* box choose the right axis (in your case *+Y to -y*)

[image]

Your mesh has been symmetrized and the floating edges has been deleted in the process.